# ADO CLI can't remove tags

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I'm using the Azure CLI with the `az boards work-item update` command (docs are [here](https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/cli/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#az_boards_work_item_update)). This is part of a larger system that reads the tags on a ticket (amongst other things) and then removes the `Ready` tag from that list and tries to set the tags back to remove it.

```sh
az boards work-item update --organization $ORG --output json --id 12345 --fields System.Tags=Android
```

When updating the tags field using `--fields System.Tags=Android` argument, this used to replace existing tags with the tag specified e.g. if a ticket had the `Android` and `Ready` tags, this would remove the `Ready` tag. However recently this seems to only be able to add tags and not remove them.

I've tried various other properties and formats, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how I can replace the tags on the ticket with the ones I'm specifying using the CLI?

EDIT: ADO community ticket raised [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ADO-CLI-no-longer-replaces-or-removes-ta/1518061?entry=myfeedback&space=21&preview2=true)

Comment: You can check this feature request. It doesn't help actually, but the comment describes the same what you notice https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/515 IMO you can create bug for this.

Comment: This is certainly a bug. Please report it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21&preview2=true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the `az boards work-item update` command is no longer removing/replacing tags with the ones that are passed, and this certainly is a bug. Please report it on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21&preview2=true) so it can be fixed.

Meanwhile, as @Fairy Xu mentioned, this behavior leaves you with the only option of making a REST call to update the work item. However, you do not have to swap your entire current setup to REST to work around the issue. The same REST call can be made via Azure CLI as well using the `az rest` command!

Here is how it can be achieved:

```
# Get current tags on the work item; Sample response: Tag1; Tag2; Tag3
$Tags = az boards work-item show --id 456 --query 'fields.\"System.Tags\"' -o tsv

# Sample headers.json
# {
#   "Authorization":"Basic OmZpYWxreG9xYnBwiZ2IyeDRyZm90d3psNmE=",
#   "Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json"
# }
#
# Sample body.json
# [
#   {
#     "op": "replace",
#     "path": "/fields/System.Tags",
#     "value": "Tag1; Tag3"
#   }
# ]

# Use az rest command to make the Update work item REST call
# In the response you'd see the System.Tags field showing only Tag1; Tag3
az rest --method patch --url https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/456?api-version=5.1 --headers '@headers.json' --body '@body.json'
```

**EDIT:**

You can deal with authentication in two ways:

- Using AAD Bearer access token

  It appears that one can use `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` as the value of `--resource` to call `az rest` as follows:

  ```
  az rest --url 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/456?api-version=5.1' --resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
  ```
- Using Basic Authentication with a PAT

  For populating the Authorization header, you first have to [generate a Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat) for your organization with the appropriate scope. Once you have it, you have to convert it to a Base64 string as follows:

  ```
  $Username=""
  $Password="<PAT>"
  $Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$Password)))
  ```

Also, be sure to include and set `Content-Type` to `application/json-patch+json` as one of the headers as `az rest` defaults it to `application/json`.

References:

- [az rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest) - Azure CLI
- [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API
- When using PowerShell, pay attention to [quoting rules](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md)
- [az curl or az rest for custom REST support (coverage) #7618](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7618)

Comment: I've raised a community ticket, so thanks for that. I'm struggling with the auth with this so haven't made it work yet, but it looks like it should. I'll award the bounty, thanks!

Comment: @JamesRiordan Sure, glad that helped, thank you! :) Yes, it was a bit of a battle to get auth right. Included some more details in the response on how I worked it through. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work without a PAT unlike the rest of the `az` command

Comment: @JamesRiordan Right, you need a PAT in this case with `az rest`. There is an alternative route as well that I was able to explore: [az devops invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops?view=azure-cli-latest#az_devops_invoke). But there are some issues with API resolution for the work item area because of which I didn't suggest this. Fixing [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/892) bug would make it a better alternative approach.

Comment: I've managed to use `az account get-access-token` and a base64 encoder to just be able to encode the token directly and use `az rest`. This is working again. Thanks very much for your help on this.

Comment: I've also worked out that the cause of this is that the CLI is using `add` instead of `replace` under the hood in the API request.

Comment: It also turns out that using `--resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` whilst logged in avoids needing to use a PAT for this? Would you mind putting that in your answer.

Comment: @JamesRiordan Great, I just got notified and came here to make the edit, only to know it was you first, haha. :D Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such method could delete specific work item tag with Rest API or Azure CLI currently.

For a work around, we need to use Azure CLI/ Rest API to get the work item tags list first. Then we could modify the tags field and update the field.

Here is my powershell example to run the Rest APIs.

```
$token = "PAT"

$url=" https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitemid}?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

$tags = $response.fields.'System.Tags'

echo $tags

$New = $tags -replace "tagname" -replace ""

echo $new


$url1 ="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitemid}?api-version=6.0"

$body = "[    


  {
    `"From`" : null,
    `"op`": `"replace`",
    `"path`": `"/fields/System.Tags`",
     `"value`" : `"$new`"
  }            
      
          ]"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PATCH -Body $body -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

Here is the docs about Rest APIs: [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: Yeah so I was doing this method with the CLI, but the issue I described above prevents this from working. This is part of a larger script that runs over the CLI so I'd rather not swap everything to REST if I don't have to.